# Django tests fails with <model> has not attribute 'object' error

Tags: django, django-models, django-tests

I have the following two models:

```py
class Resource(models.Model):
    identifier = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=now)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Resource: {self.identifier}, Time added: {self.date_added}'

class URLResource(Resource):
    url = models.URLField()

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.identifier} URL: {self.url}'
```

When I run the following commands in the django shell, everything works fine:

```py
> from user_page.models import URLResource
> URLResource.objects.create(url='abc') 
# outputs: `a3157372-7191-4d70-a4b1-c6252a2a139c URL: abc`
> URLResource.objects.get(url='abc') 
# outputs: `a3157372-7191-4d70-a4b1-c6252a2a139c URL: abc`
```

However, my seemingly trivial test case fails, even though the similar execution succeeds in the django shell:

```py
from django.test import TestCase
from users.models import CustomUser
from .models import Resource, URLResource, Record

class URLResource(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        url_resource = URLResource.objects.create(url='abc')
        print(repr(url_resource))

    def test_url(self):
        print(repr(URLResource.objects.get(url='abc')))
```

I get the following error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_url (user_page.tests.URLResource)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/readrrr/user_page/tests.py", line 26, in setUp
    url_resource = URLResource.objects.create(url='abc')
AttributeError: type object 'URLResource' has no attribute 'objects'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have named your test class the same name as the class you are trying to test. Try renaming it to `URLResourceTest`

Comment: It was so silly of me. Just realized my mistake. Thanks!